# Saying for having an argument in public that should be private

Tags: popular-refrains

Isn't their a saying when a couple fights where everyone can hear and they say things like nobody can hear? Something like, "Arguing behind a screen door" or "fighting with the screen door open."

Comment: Are you looking for *washing one's dirty linen in public?*

Comment: _Airing your dirty laundry in public_?

Comment: Same sentiment but I swear this saying specifically referenced the "screen door" since a screen door wouldn't muffle the sounds of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Is *make a spectacle of oneself* the phrase you're looking for?

> [**make a spectacle of oneself**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/make+a+spectacle+of+oneself): to call attention to one's unseemly behavior; behave foolishly or badly in public.

Comment: No. This was specifically referencing a family argument made public that should have been handled in private.

Comment: @Ditto Then, how about "hang one's dirty linen out to dry?"

Comment: Same sentiment but I swear this saying specifically referenced the "screen door" since a screen door wouldn't muffle the sounds of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to an **indiscreet conversation**. I have no reference to 'screen doors' but it reminds me of Japanese when they refer to 'rice paper walls'. Like a conversation made behind a rice paper wall, that can be easily overheard.

Comment: Exactly.  It occurred to me that it might have been a regional saying.  I'm recalling this from south Texas which I haven't lived in for a long time.

Comment: @Ditto Do they have rice-paper walls in south Texas?

Comment: No, but they have lots of screen doors.

Answer (score 0):

'Wash your dirty laundry in public' doesn't quite fit because it just doesn't address a public argument but the resulting sentiment of their action